# Add constant when replaceAll by regex

Tags: java, regex, regexp-replace

I have a regex for exclude non digit symbols:

```
\\D
```

And i need to replace all non digit symbols to spaces:

```
"145632afaf214+--)(".replaceAll("\\D", ""); // 145632214
```

Can I add to result some constant at the beginning string if i have result from the regex? I would see result like this:

```
"145632afaf214+--)(".replaceAll(improvedRegex, ""); // CONST145632214
```

However:

```
"qwqtyafaf+--)(".replaceAll(improvedRegex, ""); // ""
```

**EDIT:**
This regex adds CONST to the string but doesn't filter digits:

```
replaceAll("(^.+)", "CONST$1")
```

Comment: if i understand the question.

you can use String format at beginning of your replaceAll:

String.format("improvedRegex %s","145632afaf214+--)(".replaceAll("\\D", ""));

Comment: @fabio19933 yes, but I need to do it with one regex. I have an immutable method that takes parameters for replaceAll (regex and replacement) and returns a string.